# Rust's drain, iterator dropped ... "removes any remaining elements"

Tags: rust, iterator

On page 327 of [Programming Rust](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040385.do) you can find the following statement

> However, unlike the `into_iter()` method, which takes the collection by value and consumes it, *`drain`* merely borrows a mutable references to the collection, and when the iterator is dropped, it removes any **remaining** elements from the collection, and leaves it empty.

I'm confused at what it means it says it removes any *remaining* elements from the collection? I can see with this code when the iterator is dropped the remaining elements from `a` are still there,

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    {
        let b: Vec<i32> = a.drain(0..3).collect();
    }

    println!("Hello, world! {:?}", a);
}
```

Perhaps I'm confused at merely the wording. Is there something more to this?

Comment: There isn't a single `drain` method but rather a separate one for many kinds of collections e.g. `Vec<T>`, `HashMap<K, V>` and `String`. Does *Programming Rust* say which one it's talking about, or is it left ambiguous? [`HashSet::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.drain) does exactly what the text says.

Comment: And there is `drain_filter`, which is also implemented by `BTreeMap` and `BTreeSet`, both not imlementing `drain`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a bit imprecise wording.

The real meaning of these words is: if you drop the `drain` iterator without exhausting it, it will drop all the elements *used for its creation*. As you've asked it to use only the first three elements, it won't empty the entire vector, but rather the first part only; but it will do this even if unused:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    {
        let _ = a.drain(0..3);
    }

    println!("Hello, world! {:?}", a);
}
```

```
Hello, world! [4, 5]
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1a71d07dfd3527dc38f469900f3cc8f)

You could understand this in the following way: the "collection" mentioned here is not the initial collection the `drain` was called on, but rather is "sub-collection", specified by the passed range.